# filter reopened ticket out in mysql

Tags: mysql

I might be stuck with something silly here, but what I'm trying to do getting tickets that are in open/pending status in a db, but I wasn't able to find a solution of including tickets that have been closed at some point and then reopened.
So in the table here:
[image]

ticket 10727 won't be meeting the requirement as it will be showing up as closed if I filter out like this:

```
ticket_id NOT in 
(select zts.ticket_id
from zendesk_ticket_status zts
join zendesk_ticket zt on zts.ticket_id = zt.ticket_id 
where zts.status IN ('closed', 'solved'))
```

How do I make sure that ticket gets included?
Basically adding some sort of exception so that I also get tickets where status in ('open','pending') and updated_at > updated_at when status = 'solved'?

Comment: Just check that the most recent status is open or pending..but do you want the entire trail in your result set? or just from the most recent closed,solved (if there is one) or from new if there isn't one?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more efficient ways to do it, but you could do something like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT zts.ticket_id
FROM zendesk_ticket zts
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ticket_id, MAX(updated_at) AS close_date 
  FROM zendesk_ticket 
  WHERE status IN ('closed', 'solved')
  GROUP BY ticket_id
) AS closed_tickets ON zts.ticket_id = closed_tickets.ticket_id
WHERE closed_tickets.ticket_id IS NULL
OR zts.updated_at > closed_tickets.close_date
```

The `closed_tickets` subquery should take for each ticket the maximum date where it was `closed` or `solved`, and then `LEFT JOIN` that result to the main table, in order to take only tickets without an entry in the subquery, or with a more recent update

Answer (score -1):

Could you not just look at the latest status for every ticket?:

```
SELECT zt.ticket_id 
FROM zendesk_ticket zt
JOIN zendesk_ticket_status zts on zts.ticket_id = zt.ticket_id 
WHERE zts.id = (
   SELECT TOP 1 zts2.id
   FROM zendesk_ticket_status zts2
   WHERE zts2.ticket_id  = zt.ticket_id 
   ORDER BY zts2.updated_at DESC
)
AND zts.status IN ('open', 'pending', 'closed', 'solved', ...)
```